# Passing Variables by Reference in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, center

I am trying to display and center a map for the users current location.  Everything works fine if I manually enter a hard coded latitude and longitude, but these needs to be dynamic as one user often changes location.

I suspect I am making a basic mistake, but my logic seems like it is correct to me.  Please check my work and let me know what I am doing wrong? The line that is remarked out with Latitude and Longitude is the line I want to use instead of the previous line with the hard coded values.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>W123</title>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>

</head>

<body>
    <div id='printoutPanel'></div>
    <div id='myMap' style='width: 100vw; height: 100vh;'></div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

        function showlocation() {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation);
        }

        function getLocation(position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            }

        function loadMapScenario() {
            var mapOptions = {
                credentials: 'My API key code goes here',
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(39.1887643719098, -92.8261546188403),
                //center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude),
                mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
                zoom: 8
            };

            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), mapOptions);
            var urlTemplate = 'http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-{timestamp}/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.png';
            var timestamps = ['900913-m50m', '900913-m45m', '900913-m40m', '900913-m35m', '900913-m30m', '900913-m25m', '900913-m20m', '900913-m15m', '900913-m10m', '900913-m05m', '900913'];
            var tileSources = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < timestamps.length; i++) {
                var tileSource = new Microsoft.Maps.TileSource({
                    uriConstructor: urlTemplate.replace('{timestamp}', timestamps[i])
                });
                tileSources.push(tileSource);
            }
            var animatedLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.AnimatedTileLayer({ mercator: tileSources, frameRate: 500 });
            map.layers.insert(animatedLayer);
        }

    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?branch=experimental&callback=loadMapScenario' async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you change your title to 'Passing Variables in Javascript'? Java and Javascript are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pass in the latitude and longitude into your `loadMapScenario` function as seen below

```
function loadMapScenario(latitude,longitude) {
      ....your code here....
}
```

Change your callback in the bing map include to a new function like "mapUserLocation" then have mapUserLocation perform the following tasks

```
function mapUserLocation() {
     // code here to get the latitude and longitude from users position
     loadMapScenario(latitude,longitude);
}
```

Comment: so if I understand correctly, the function I am using to get the latitude and longitude are in the wrong place.  I need to move this inside the "function loadMapScenario" function?

Comment: I figured out what you were saying and that fixes my issue.  It is working fine for me now.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: @CarlAydelotte - sorry I did not see your first comment sooner.  Glad it is working for you, happy to help :)